# strcmp not working, finds it on second loop iteration

Tags: c, pointers, strcmp

```
int compare_filenames(char* data, char* filename){
    //note: we only have 31 directory/file entries within a block
    int i;
    int offset;
    //printf("argument %s\n", filename);
    for(i = 0; i < BLOCK_SIZE; i+=16){
        if(strcmp(filename, &data[i])){
            offset = i + 12;

            return data[i+12];// double check here
        }

    }
    return ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND; //didn't find it within
}
```

for some reson strcmp goes through two loop iterations even when the first element is right at the beginning

Comment: I'm going to guess `strcmp()` isn't broken. [First rule of programming: It's your fault](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html)

Comment: Besides the answers below: your local variable `offset` isn't used. And now might be a good time to start using "const". And 12 and 16 should be named constants. Methinks your company needs more code review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

strcmp() return 0 when they are equal.  You are returning if one is greater or less than the other.

Answer (score 3):

You want to do `strcmp(filename, &data[i]) == 0`.

0 indicates match between strings, which evaluated as false...